spring cloud secrets manager 3.2.0 not refreshing @Value
I am using Spring Cloud Secrets Starter for secrets manager on AWS; here is my dependency. I am running on springboot > 3.2.10. I am using kotlin and the values load correctly on startup but don't get refreshed.
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.awspring.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-starter-secrets-manager</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

I can see in the logs that polling is happening, reload was detected, and context was restarted. The issue I am having is my @Value doesn't get refreshed. I added a @PostContruct and can see the Config is being reloaded.
I have tried like every option and combination of @Configuration, @ConfigurationProperties, and @RefreshScope.
For starters is there a working example that I can refer to? Here is my cloud config under spring: in application.yml.
Logs with was cloud in debug -
2024-12-04 12:22:10,934 INFO  class=i.a.c.a.c.r.ConfigurationChangeDetector thread=spring-cloud-aws-secretsmanager-ThreadPoolTaskScheduler-1       description="Reloading using strategy: io.awspring.cloud.autoconfigure.config.reload.ConfigurationUpdateStrategy@1c04eb6a"
2024-12-04 12:22:10,974 INFO  class=o.s.boot.SpringApplication thread=spring-cloud-aws-secretsmanager-ThreadPoolTaskScheduler-1       description="The following 1 profile is active: "uat""
2024-12-04 12:22:10,976 INFO  class=o.s.boot.SpringApplication thread=spring-cloud-aws-secretsmanager-ThreadPoolTaskScheduler-1       description="Started application in 0.04 seconds (process running for 1091.236)"
2024-12-04 12:22:11,005 INFO  class=c.l.r.g.d.config.AppConfig$Companion thread=spring-cloud-aws-secretsmanager-ThreadPoolTaskScheduler-1       description="reloading secret post field -- thisisatestsecretfirstloadchange115"

application.yml
        aws:
            secretsmanager:
                reload:
                    strategy: refresh
                    period: 1m
                region: us-east-1
                enabled: true
                endpoint:  http://localhost:4566 

A sample of appconfig
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties
open class AppConfig: SecretsManagerConfig() {

    @Value("\${testing.password:}")
    @get:RefreshScope
    var testPasswordStringValue: String = ""
        get() = field
        set(value) {
            field = value
        }

    @PostConstruct
    open fun afterLoad() { 
        LOGGER.info("reloading secret post reload -- {}", this.testPasswordStringValue)
    }
} ```

